# Mondrian schema cache control

Tags: caching, pentaho, business-intelligence, cache-control, mondrian

I am having trouble clearing the Mondrian schema cache on my BI server. I go to 
**Tools**->**Refresh**->**Mondrian cache**. But **clear_mondrian_schema_cache.xaction** does not seem to be clearing the cache.

I need the results to update as the source data changes, but I seem to keep getting cached results every time I issue a query.

Can someone help me with the API to enable periodic schema cache refresh?

Comment: Have you read this? http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/cache_control.php#CacheControl_API

Comment: Yes, I have read that. does not seem to be helping.

Comment: did you find any solution to this cache refresh issue , Any inputs from your side would help me @JyotiSaini

Answer (score 1):

i use the following bash script. which works nicely without any API faff :).
it is the equivalent of clicking `tools > refresh > mondrian cache` in the console.

the variable `schema` is the name of the schema which you see in the schema workbench app

```
#!bin/bash
#
# script to clean pentaho cache

user=XXX
pass=XXX
host=localhost
schema=Reporting%20schemas

wget --no-check-certificate http://${host}:2310/pentaho/content/analyzer/ajax/clearCache?catalog=${schema}\&userid=${user}\&password=${pass}
```

credit to pentaho support